# Shell script with args, where the args are files with spaces

Tags: shell, image-processing, imagemagick, zsh

I wish to use a shell script that accepts a for loop of a directory for an imagemagick script. The shell script is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ~/scripts/mkhdr.sh
                                                                                                                                         
convert -gaussian $1 $2 - | composite -compose overlay $2 - $3
```

and the for loop is thus:

```
for i in *.(tif|jpg);do;echo converting $i;~/scripts/mkhdr.sh 3 ./$i ./SSP_JPGs/$i:r.jpg;done
```

Works fine on a directory of files without spaces. Fails on a directory where files names contains spaces.

#### Update:

thanks to [Adrian Frühwirth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612462/adrian-fruhwirth), here's what works:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ~/scripts/mkhdr.sh
                                                                                                                                         
convert -gaussian "$1" "$2" - | composite -compose overlay "$2" - "$3"
```

Command line:

```
for file in *.(tif|jpg);do;echo converting "${file}";~/scripts/mkhdr.sh 3 "${file}" "/Users/me/Desktop/${file}";done
```

Comment: is it /bin/sh or /bin/zsh, very different set of options available. Good luck.

Comment: I prefer /bin/zsh; /bin/sh was incidental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong with both snippets you posted. Let's start with the second:

```
for i in *.(tif|jpg); do
    echo converting $i
    ~/scripts/mkhdr.sh 3 ./$i ./SSP_JPGs/$i:r.jpg
done
```

1. As already pointed out, you need to quote your variables to account for spaces in filenames.
2. I am not familiar with `zsh`'s `:r` syntax, but since you are searching for `.jpg` AND `.tif` files `:r.jpg` would not account for the `.tif` files.

Now the first snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ~/scripts/mkhdr.sh

convert -gaussian $1 $2 - | composite -compose overlay $2 - $3
```

Even if you quote your variables in the other snippet, they are unquoted here and once again, filenames with spaces will be a problem.

Now let's apply some fixes, starting with the conversation snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ~/scripts/mkhdr.sh

convert -gaussian "$1" "$2" - | composite -compose overlay "$2" - "$3"
```

- Always quote your variables to be on the safe side.

And the calling snippet:

```
for file in *.tif *.jpg; do
        echo "converting '${file}'"
        ~/scripts/mkhdr.sh 3 "${file}" "./SSP_JPGs/${file%.*}"
done
```

- Quoted variables.
- Changed the `*.(tif|jpg)` syntax to `*. tif *.jpg`. This should work in all `zsh`, `bash` and `ksh93`, but you don't have to use this.
- Changed `$i:r.jpg` to `${i%.*}`. This removes the shorted match of `.*` from the back of the value of `i`, which happens to be the file extension. This should work in all `zsh`, `bash` and `ksh93`.

Comment: Re: ":r.jpg" is _precisely_ what I want in this context, given I'm using convert to, well, _convert_ the graphic files. Also, my construct of *.(jpg|tif) works better than your space-delimited selector. If there are no tifs in the directory, the script ends on that line. Otherwise, this nails it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read`; then quote all occurrences of `$i`:

```
ls *.tif *.jpg | while read i; do
  echo converting "$i";
  ~/scripts/mkhdr.sh 3 "./$i" "./SSP_JPGs/$i:r.jpg";
done
```

I'm not sure about the `$i:r.jpg` part, it appends **:r.jpg** to the filename ??

Comment: The `:r` syntax appears to be something zsh borrowed from csh; it yields the "root" of a file name, i.e., the name with any suffix removed. `file=foo.txt; echo $file:r` will print `foo`.

Comment: The `for` loop should work (I think) as long as the references to `$i` are double-quoted.

Comment: Sigh; no, not working. The script continues to try the parse the spaces in the file names as unique files. You are correct ":r.jpg" does what Keith identifies, though I've done this under bash for years.

Comment: This is because your `mkhdr.sh` still has unquoted variables (see my answer). Either way, [just don't ever parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).